# Gold badge for accepted answers?

Tags: discussion, badges

I'm curious why there are two silver badges for accepted answers—Enlightened and Guru—but no gold ones.

I'm not saying every single badge should fit into the 10/40/100 b/s/g format, but it does strike me as unusual that, again, there are two silver badges for this but no gold ones.

**EDIT**

Ok, there's the [unsung hero](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/226/unsung-hero) badge, but that's a bit different.  I'm talking about badges for highly-rated accepted answers—like Enlightened and Guru

Comment: What about [Unsung Hero](http://stackoverflow.com/badges/226/unsung-hero) badge? It's gold and it's rewarded for accepted answers.

Comment: @ShaDowWizArd - yeah, that's a bit different though - I edited my question to account for it though

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm actually in favor of a gold badge for accepted answers.

Currently you can get Populist for ***not*** having the accepted answer - which seems a bit odd to me.

Secondly, when a question/answer goes completely viral, the OP typically gets 3 gold badges (Great/Famous/Stellar Question). But the answers get at most 1 gold badge (Great Answer).

(If you want examples, just run down the list of [top questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=votes)...)

So I'd advocate a gold "Professor" badge for answers with a score of 250 + accepted.

Of course the 250 can be adjusted.
Here's an idea of how many will be awarded at different thresholds:

- [150 votes - 519](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=isaccepted%3A1+is%3Aanswer+votes%3A150&submit=search)
- [200 votes - 294](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=isaccepted%3A1+is%3Aanswer+votes%3A200&submit=search)
- [250 votes - 188](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=isaccepted%3A1+is%3Aanswer+votes%3A250&submit=search)
- [300 votes - 126](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=isaccepted%3A1+is%3Aanswer+votes%3A300&submit=search)
- [400 votes - 69](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=isaccepted%3A1+is%3Aanswer+votes%3A400&submit=search)
- [500 votes - 39](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=isaccepted%3A1+is%3Aanswer+votes%3A500&submit=search)

In all cases, this will badge will be extremely difficult to obtain and will probably be once-in-a-lifetime for most users that do get them. (So I'm not sure if this is good thing or a bad thing...)

<sub>*Disclaimer, I have two highly voted accepted answers. So I am ***extremely heavily*** biased towards a gold badge for a highly voted accepted answer. :P</sub>

Answer (score 10):

There's already a gold badge for answers with 100 votes, regardless of its accepted state: [great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/25/great-answer). Perhaps they dropped the "accepted" requirement because with so much votes, the answer surely must be great. I don't see how another badge would be useful.

Note that there's no silver badge for an unaccepted answer with 40 votes and also note that "Enlightenend" adds the requirement that the answer must be the *first* answer ever on the question.

Comment: That sounds logical - like you said, an answer with 100 votes is great with or without a checkmark.  I'll leave this open a bit more to see if anything has anything else to add